# Non-EU citizen living in Switzerland and traveling within Schengen area while the passport is with the US consulate for issuing a visa

Tags: visas

Do flights from Switzerland to Germany have an immigration check? Is my Legitimation Card enough for traveling between these two countries? Does the US consulate provide a letter stating that they are with my passport while issuing the visa or something?

Comment: What do you mean with “legitimation card”? A Swiss residence permit (Ausländerausweis / Livret pour étranger)? A document issued by another country?

Comment: @Relaxed https://www.eda.admin.ch/eda/fr/dfae/dfae/organisation-dfae/secretariat-etat/protocole/regime-priveleges-immunites-suisse/sejour-suisse/carte-legitimation-dfae.html

Comment: Can't you get a second passport?

Comment: Wouldn't it make my newly issued US visa invalid?

Comment: I don't see why, it's reasonably common.

Comment: Are you in Switzerland based on a regular or official/diplomatic passport?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella why would that matter?

Comment: This is an indirect answer, but travelling by train instead of by air could solve your problem. All flights in the EU have some id check, trains from Switzerland to Germany in general do not.

Comment: @phoog A diplomatic/service passport holder *may* require specific procedures depending on the country

Comment: @NicolasFormichella usually the procedures are more closely bound to the purpose of travel rather than the category of passport being used.  That's certainly the case in the US.  It might be possible to get away with not having a passport when traveling to Germany from Switzerland on official diplomatic business, but the travel to Germany isn't official, so that possibility isn't relevant to this question.  Similarly, one with a CDL in Switzerland enjoys the same immunity regardless of passport type; the crucial factor is the _note verbale_ from the mission or international organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do flights from Switzerland to Germany have an immigration check?

No immigration check (i.e. you are very unlikely to see a police officer) but airlines frequently do check passports. Even if that's not always the case, I wouldn't rely on not having to show your passport. There is also always a chance that a customs officer wants to talk to you.

> Is my Legitimation Card enough for traveling between these two countries?

Probably not but I am not sure. Even if it shouldn't be accepted (and I don't know that for a fact), it could still be enough to bluff your way through. I once flew with someone who was able to board a flight out of Switzerland with a residence permit from some other European country (after losing their national ID card shortly before boarding). But it was a flight to her country of residence and it required a whole lot of discussion.

> Does the US consulate provide a letter stating that they are with my passport while issuing the visa or something?

I don't think that would really help you. Airlines are more interested in checking that your document is on their list and reducing liability than understanding your situation.

Note that it is also required to hold a passport while in Germany and you probably have to worry about the flight back to Switzerland.

Comment: Yeah, for what I gathered the trip back from Germany would be the hardest part :/

Comment: @travelingfromswitzerland I suppose you're not traveling to Germany or to the US on official business?

Comment: US yes, Germany no

Comment: @travelingfromswitzerland it depends on the airline, I believe.  I've flown from Geneva to Spain a few times and there was one flight where I don't think they checked any ID until boarding.  I thought about using my residence permit but in the end didn't try it, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: @travelingfromswitzerland so is it an A or G visa?  If so you should have the passport back in a matter of days if not hours.

Comment: I have also flown from Stuttgart with no ID check whatsoever (not even at the gate). It does happen, even in Germany, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: If the airline checks your id in Germany seem to me to depend both on the airline and the airport. For example, when flying (domestic or intra-schengen) with Lufthansa from Munich, they do not check ids. It is however not uncommon that other airlines check your id when flying from Munich and I have also experienced that Lufthansa checks my id when flying from other airports. Legally speaking, you are required to carry your passport when crossing the German border even if there are no systematic checks.